# Services-centered design

Tags: resource-request, introductory-lesson, labs, course-design

I am having some difficulties to find free access documentation, lecture notes, scientific papers, or books, on a course I have to give. Course topic is "Services-centered design".

Course objectives are:

- Use advanced design techniques applicable to large service oriented software systems.
- Apply advanced design techniques for a specific system.
- Evaluate design decisions.

Course content is:
Concepts
Development cycle and life cycle (service oriented)
Principles of service-oriented application development
Templates
Protocols and standards
Approaches and implementation

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that the right keywords for what I was looking for, given the course objectives and the course content are:

- Service-oriented software engineering
- Service-driven software
  engineering
- Service-oriented software architecture
- Service-driven software architecture
- Services-centered software architecture design, ...